# Does firebase make distinctions between a row and a column?

Tags: firebase

When using the original Firebase database in the web console and clicking the plus button to add a new child to an object - is this similar to adding a new row of data in a relational database or is it more like adding an attribute in a row. Or something completely different?

Comment: Firebase consists of 15+ products. Which one are you talking about? A screenshot of what you're looking at would probably be helpful too.

Comment: What 15 products?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/

Comment: Well, firebase is firebase

Comment: It is indeed. But from the description you provided I have no idea which "add" button, "child" or "thing" you're talking about, so it makes it rather hard to help. Unless cadmium's answer is indeed what you were looking for, I recommend that you clarify your question to improve your chances of getting help.

Comment: There's only one place where you can add a child to a thing in firebase. Yes, my question has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the original firebase database product there is no real concept of columns or rows, it is just a simple tree structure.

You have a field name and a field value which can be either a literal value (string, int, etc) or an array of more name/value objects - but everything is part of the same tree. You can nest as deep as you want to go, but you probably want to keep it pretty shallow.

I found it helpful to think of the entire database as a single json object - **when you click the add button you are effectivly adding a field to an object**.

[image]

Firebase does have a newer database called Firestore (in beta) that acts a little more like a standard document db (such as mongodb) with multiple collections, richer objects, and more advanced querying.